# initialization of LD_LIBRARY_PATH in BEGIN block fails

Tags: perl, oracle, dbi, dbd

I have to add /oracle/v10.2.0/lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH to use DBI module to connect to Oracle.

If I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in shell before executing perl script, everything is ok.

But it does not work from script:

```
BEGIN {
  $ENV{'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'}='/oracle/v10.2.0/lib';
}
use DBI;
```

When I execute the script I get the error:

> install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load '/usr/apps/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i686-linux/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module DBD::Oracle: libclntsh.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/apps/perl5/5.8.8/i686-linux/DynaLoader.pm line 230.
>    at (eval 3) line 3
>   Compilation failed in require at (eval 3) line 3.
>   Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected
>    at /var/tmp/getTraceDB.pl line 23

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BEGIN {
$ENV{'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'}.='/oracle/v10.2.0/lib';
exec($^X, $0, @ARGV);
}
use DBI;
```

Refer [Runtime Linker and LD_LIBRARY_PATH](http://pages.swcp.com/~breadfan/runtime_linker/ld_library_path.html) for proper description.

Comment: Exec is the right way, but I think you'd get yourself into an endless loop there. You should only exec when the right path wasn't already in `$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}` because there is no tail condition.

Comment: with exec it's working, thanks. The only problem is that perl debugger ("-d") does not work anymore...exec executes script straight away

Answer (score 0):

Far better would be to have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set in your `.profile` or similar. It has to be visible at the time the ELF loader starts up, which is waaay before even `/usr/bin/perl` is running, let alone the `BEGIN` block of your script. The `exec()` trick works by restarting the entire binary if it had to add the path, but better would be for it to always exist in your environment always.